# RequiredFieldValidator to validate a disabled textBox

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I've got a TextBox in which user can input a their desired username.
Underneath I've got a checkbox that once clicked it copies the user's email adress into the textfield and then disable it to prevent further changes. This feature is implemented by using jQuery.

The problem is that I've got a RequiredFieldValidator on that TextBox and it looks like it can't validate a disabled textfield, even if the value is set.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference: I fixed this by setting the property "readonly" instead of "disabled".

Comment: On serverside? For me, setting readonly on the client side does not work at all. On the client side, it uses this caseing: "readOnly"

Comment: @Marcel I also tried ReadOnly = true on server side, but my Validator still doesn't read the value changed by the Jquery.Did you manage to avoid the validator triggered ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom validator control like in this sample:

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/